# Jquery DataTable not working properly

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using datatable plugin but having an issue with the sorting. default sorting order is asc and i want data in descending order when the page is loaded.
following is the script i'm using for initialization:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
App.init();
});
```

also tried to use this
`$('#sample_1').dataTable();`
but it effects the menus. Menu sliders stops working and datatable also not working properly with this.
and there is no error in console.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please edit your question to include your actual dataTable initialization code (presumably, you have this in your .init() function) as well as the HTML of the elements being affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your init code and HTML, we can't really point out what is going wrong.

If your table is visible before the DataTable is initialized, then you'll need to make sure it is sorted correctly in the original HTML.

When initializing the DataTable you'll want to set up the initial sorting - e.g. for descending sort on the first column:

```
    $table = $("#sample_1").dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered adjust_table" style="table-layout:fixed;" id="sample_1"><thead>

    <tr>
        <th  class="">Order ID</th>
        <th class="">Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th  class="">2001</th>
        <th class="">John</th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <th  class="">2002</th>
        <th class="">Marry</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And following is the init code:
App.init();